# Query on ANTLR Grammar

Tags: antlr

I am creating ANTLR Grammar for below calculator program.

```
1   program       ->  stmt_list $$
2   stmt_list     ->  stmt_list stmt | E
3   stmt          ->  ID := expr | READ ID | WRITE expr
4   expr          ->  term | expr add_op term
5   term          ->  factor | term mult_op factor
6   factor        ->  ( expr ) | ID | LITERAL
7   add_op        ->  + | -
8   mult_op       ->  * | /
```

But I am stuck while creating ANTLR grammar version.I wrote below -

```
grammar Calculator;
// Lexer specification

fragment LETTER 
    :   'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment DIGIT  
    :   '0'..'9';
ID  :   LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;
NUM :   DIGIT+;
ADD :   '+';
SUB :   '-';
MUL :   '*';
DIV :   '/';
LPAR    :   '(';
RPAR    :   ')';
ASSIGN  :   '=';
NEWLINE :   '\r'?'\n';
WS  :   (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+ { skip(); };

// Parser specification

program :   stmt_list NEWLINE* EOF;

stmt_list
    :   stmt
    ;
stmt    :   ID ASSIGN expr
                | READ ID
                | WRITE expr
    ;

expr    :       term (ADD term | SUB term)*
    ; 
term    :       factor (MUL factor | DIV factor)*
        ;
factor  :       LPAR expr RPAR
        |   ID
        |   NUM
    ;
```

I am not sure how to express this portion 'READ ID | WRITE expr'. When I try to compile it gives me below error -

warning(105): Calculator.g:29:19: no lexer rule corresponding to token: WRITE
warning(105): Calculator.g:28:19: no lexer rule corresponding to token: READ

I am new to ANTLR.Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

`READ` and `WRITE` are probably keywords, so you have to define them in your grammar too (like you did for `ID`):

```
READ: 'READ';
WRITE: 'WRITE';
```

and

```
LITERAL: (LETTER | DIGIT)+;
```

as an example for the `LITERAL` spec.

Comment: Hi,I have updated following grammar file. Would like to compute using visitor pattern.
program : stmt_list+;
stmt_list
 : stmt
 ;
stmt : expr NEWLINE                # 'printExpr'
 | ID ASSIGN expr      # 'assigned'
 |    NEWLINE                     # 'blank'
        ;

expr :      term (ADD term | SUB term)*   #'AddSub'
 ; 
term :      factor (MUL factor | DIV factor)*  #'MulDiv'
        ;
factor :     LPAR expr RPAR       #'parens'
        |  ID                    #'id'
        |  NUM                   #'num'

Comment: Hi,I have updated following grammar file. Would like to compute using visitor pattern.
stmt : expr NEWLINE                # 'printExpr'
 | ID ASSIGN expr      # 'assigned'
 |    NEWLINE                     # 'blank'
        ;
expr :      term (ADD term | SUB term)*   #'AddSub'
 ; 
term :      factor (MUL factor | DIV factor)*  #'MulDiv'
        ;
 but it is giving below error line 8:46 no viable alternative at character '#'
line 9:46 no viable alternative at character '#'. Am I giving some incorrect syntax?